# Jdbc template cant find stored procedure on DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, h2

I have a project that connects to an Oracle DB that contains some packages and stored procedures. The problem is that Spring JDBC returns an error message when try to call a stored procedure from a REST web service.

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
>   [{call PKG_RECLAMO.SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO()}]; 
>   SQL state [90022]; error code [90022]; Función "SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO" 
>   no encontrada
>   **Function "SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO" not found; SQL statement:
>   call PKG_RECLAMO.SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO()  [90022-197];**  nested exception is 
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Función "SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO" no encontrada
>   Function "SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO" not found; SQL statement:
>   call PKG_RECLAMO.SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO()  [90022-197]

some lines below ... shows another message ...

> Caused by: **org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException**: Función "SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO" 
>   no encontrada
>   Function "SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO" not found; SQL statement:
>   call PKG_RECLAMO.SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO()  [90022-197]
>     at 
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)

It seems that Spring JDBC template is looking for the procedure in H2 DB and is not using the Oracle connector instead.

```
@Repository
public class ClsReclamoDao implements ClsIReclamoDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public Long insertReclamo(ClsReclamoRequestBean objRequest) {

        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new 
            SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withCatalogName("PKG_RECLAMO")
            .withProcedureName("SP_INSERTAR_RECLAMO");

        SqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("p_nuReclamoTipoReclamo",
                       "123")
            .addValue("p_nuAnonimo", "1")
        [more parameters...]

       Map<String, Object> returnMap = jdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);
       ...
    }
```

These are my POM dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracleConnector</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There is a way to tell spring that always uses the Oracle Connector instead of H2 DB ?

**Update**

When I try to put SCOPE = TEST on H2 dependency, like this...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Application fails at start and show this error message.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and 
no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

    Consider the following:
         If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), 
             please put it on the classpath.
         If you have database settings to be loaded from a 
             particular profile you may need to activate it 
             (no profiles are currently active).
```

**Update**

this is my application properties file

```
spring.jmx.default-domain:appOracleService
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=userdb
spring.datasource.password=passdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

## LOGGING
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
logging.exception-conversion-word=%wEx 
logging.file.max-history=0 
logging.file.max-size=10MB 
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
```

Comment: How is that `jdbcTemplate` object configured?

Comment: @AndrewS My class is marked with Repository and JdbcTemplate is with Autowired 

    <Repository>
    public class ClsMedioCompraDao implements ClsIMedioCompraDao {

        <Autowired>
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Comment: Could you show int the question a content of your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file ?

Comment: @krokodilko sure, check my update.

Comment: Thank you. Please also show a code that initializes `jdbcTemplate` variable (which is then used here: `....  SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)..withCatalogName( .....`).

Comment: jdbcTemplate variable is anotated with **Autowired** and my class is annotated with **Repository**. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research, I realized that this maven section is breaking all the connection stuff.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I want to register generated jasper files into the class path.

But at this moment, I don't understand why this maven code breaks all Spring JDBC stuff.